# Kendo control value in the event is the controls previous value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to understand why this isn't working. If i set the value of myTextBox to 5 then trigger the change event. the value for my myTextBox is null. If i change the value to 10 then fire the event again, the value will be the previous one (5). I've compared it to one of the many textboxes working on the form and they appear the same. The only difference is the value property in the wrapper object is set in the ones that work but behind in the one that doesn't. Digging into the both objects element property, i see the values are correct and current. Any help would be appreciated.

Model Property

```
    [UIHint("Decimal")]
    [Display(Name = "Example")]
    public decimal? MyTxt{ get; set; }
```

Template (Decimal.cshtml):

```
@model decimal?

@{
    var defaultHtmlAttributesObject = new { style = "width:100%" };
    var htmlAttributesObject = ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? new { };
    var htmlAttributes = Html.MergeHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributesObject, defaultHtmlAttributesObject);
}


@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m)
            .Format("#.00")
            .HtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)
)
```

UI Declaration

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTxt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @style="width: 100%", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

Javascript:

```
var myTextBox = $('#MyTxt').data('kendoNumericTextBox');

$(document).on('change', '#foo', function(){
       var test = myTextBox.value();
})
```

**Update:**

In the document ready function i was binding the change event like this:

```
$('#MyTxt').change({ source: $('#MyTxt'), destination: someObject, isTwoMan: true, crewType: LaborType.Set }, SomeCalcFunction);
```

The jQuery change event fires nefore the kendo one thus the delay in getting the correct value. The fix was to read the manual and bind to the event the kendo way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was in the way i was binding to the change event.

```
$('#MyTxt').change({ source: $('#MyTxt'), destination: someObject, isTwoMan: true, crewType: LaborType.Set }, SomeCalcFunction);
```

will fire before the kendo event does. Changing it the kendo way fixed my issue

```
$("#MyTxt").bind("change", function (e) {

    var event = jQuery.Event('change', {
        source: $("#MyTxt"),
        destination: someObject,
        isTwoMan: true,
        crewType: LaborType.Set
    });
    SomeCalcFunction(event);
});
```